# siunitx: Adding commas when printing a variable

Tags: siunitx, counters

I have an itemized list which adds numbers to a counter. At the top (after you compile it twice) it prints the total sum. It works correctly but I am trying to add commas to the sum, so it will print "16,000" instead of 16000. All the examples of siunitx I have seen assume constants, not variables.

Here's the relevant portion of my LaTeX file:

```
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\newtotcounter{ftotal}


\subsection*{Counting}

\vspace{0.1in}
\noindent

Total amount: \$\total{ftotal}.

\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.45in}
\item Item1, \$1000.
\addtocounter{ftotal}{1000}
\item Item2, \$3000.
\addtocounter{ftotal}{3000}
\item Item2, \$12000.
\addtocounter{ftotal}{12000}
\item ...
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `siunitx` features when printing numbers, you need to use `\num`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\newtotcounter{ftotal}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Counting}

Total amount: \$\num{\the\totvalue{ftotal}}.

\begin{itemize}
\item Item1, \$\num{1000}.
\addtocounter{ftotal}{1000}
\item Item2, \$\num{3000}.
\addtocounter{ftotal}{3000}
\item Item3, \$\num{12000}.
\addtocounter{ftotal}{12000}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\num{\total{ftotal}}` would not work.

[image]

Comment: With sinuitx, you can use  `\qty{1000}[\$]{}` to format numbers with currencies.

Comment: @ArTourter I'm not sure it's better.